# ActiveX seems to mount asynchronously

Tags: c++, reactjs, activex

IE11.
I have an ActiveX component with some API, and an application on the top of ReactJS to use it. Consider next React Component code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.mountActiveX();
    this.updateActiveX();
}

mountActiveX() {
    this.refs.content.getDOMNode().innerHTML = `
        <object
            classid='CLSID:9F52F906-94D1-4E33-85E4-62A9A68EF545'
            name="client"
            ref="client"
        ></object>
    `;
    this._client = window["client"];
    this._isMounted = true;
}

updateActiveX() {
    if (this._client && this._isMounted) {
        /* use ActiveX API here */
    }
}
```

When I try to invoke some ActiveX API method in `updateActiveX`, IE raises an error: `Cannot create a top-level child window.`. But, if I defer `updateActiveX` method (due `setTimeout`, for example), there is no error and API is available.

How could I handle the ActiveX component mounting?

Comment: Solved - I used to show\hide ActiveX depends on `_isMounted` flag with CSS classes: during the initial mounting of React Component class `hide` was removed, **immediately** after that `componentDidMount`, 'udpateActiveX' and ActiveX API method  were called, I guess, browser did not render appearence of ActiveX on the page *exactly* synchronous - when ActiveX API was called, control was still *hide* - that's why `Cannot create a top-level child window` raised. Check of control visibility is required.